# Maxent Error reading output row and column

Tags: maxent

I need to predict geographical distribution of an insect using maxent. I have converted the bioclim data variable to ascii format to use with the collection records. After loading the files and when maxent has successfully written the output ascii file then an error message comes up. it says that there is error reading the output row x and column y. The html file is therefore empty. Could someone be knowing what I can do about this?

Comment: Can you please give more information?: How do you convert the bioclim data? Can you open ascii file in some desktop GIS (QGIS, ArcGIS)? When the error shows and what exactly says?

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit late, but I have encountered a similar error dozens of times and finally found one particular trigger for it in my case.

I am using Maxent 3.4.1 with `kuenm` package for automated runs. This error coupld pop up accidentally, but it was more likely to pop up when I tried to run model projection in parallel **from two separate instances of `R` or Maxent**. The error was like that:

```
Error reading file /media/tapirus/Hard_Tran_2TB/nauka/Vacc/sdm/kuenm/vaccinium2/vacc-only/scenarios/background_swd/miroc/maxent.cache/bio19.mxe 
row 271 column 4490: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

A simple relaunch of Maxent projection script (avoiding several scripts launched at once) is enough to cope with this error.